# Stored procedure show me [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)] in laravel

Tags: stored-procedures

I wanna use stored procedure.

but this code show me error.

```
    public function post(Request $request) 
    {    
       $post = new Post;
       $form = $request->all();
       unset($form['_token']);
       
       $file_name = $request
                    ->file('path')
                    ->getClientOriginalName();

       $request->file('path')->storeAs('public', $file_name);
               
       DB::select('exec insert_post(?,?,?)', array($request->name, $request->message, $file_name));

       return view('welcome');
```

instead of this. same error.

```
      DB::statement(
            'call insert_post(?,?,?)',
            [$request->name, $request->message, $file_name]
        );
```

instead of this. work.

```
        $post->name    = $request->name;
        $post->message = $request->message;
        $post->path    = $file_name; 
        $post->save();
```

stored procedure

```
MariaDB [laravel2]> create procedure insert_post(IN x varchar(20), IN y text, IN z text)
    -> begin
    -> insert into posts (name, message, path) values(x, y, z);
    -> end
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.011 sec)
```